# How to Create an HTML Form That Emails Responses to Your Inbox without PHP?

Tags: html, forms, email

My website is made out of only HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Is there a way to send emails of responses from an HTML form without using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use mailto method like below..

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>

<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will it send this directly to the user?

Comment: no it will open your mail and fetch text that you write in inputs and then you need to click send button then it will send

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:email@provider.com">
<textarea name="foo">your message</textarea>
<button type="submit">ok</button>
</form>
```

i guess this should try to send the contents to your mailbox

but thats way **unsafe** and **very vulnerable for spam and bots** i would **not reccomend** using **this code**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/formspree/formspree

```
<form action="http://formspree.io/you@email.com" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="email" name="_replyto">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```